# use tinyMCE with angular 6 without apikey (free)

Tags: angular, tinymce, free, api-key

I tried to install tinyMCE with angular 6. I am following the docs on https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular2/.

Everything OK but I must to have an apiKey to use the tinyMCE cloud.

I got the error : "This domain is not registered with TinyMCE Cloud. Start a free trial to discover our premium cloud services and pro support."

I want to use the self hosted version without apiKey.

So as explained on the doc https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular2/#loadingtinymcebyyourself we can hosting the tinymce.min.js to disable apiKey.

How to add tinymce.min.js properly with angular 6 ?

Answer (score 14):

**1) install tinymce for angular 2+ :**

install tinymce angular npm module

```
npm install @tinymce/tinymce-angular
```

import **EditorModule** on *app.module.ts*

```
import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';
```

add **EditorModule** to imports on *app.module.ts*

```
imports: [
...,
EditorModule
]
```

**2) host the tinymce JS**

install the tinymce npm module :

```
npm install tinymce --save
```

import styles on *angular.json*

```
"styles": [
  ...,
  "node_modules/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css",
  "node_modules/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css",
  "node_modules/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.inline.min.css"
]
```

import scripts on `angular.json`

```
"script": [
  ...,
  "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
  "node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js"
]
```

**3) use tinyMCE on HTML file**

add this code to use :

```
<editor [(ngModel)]="dataModel"></editor>
```

Comment: Since Tinymce 5 those links don't work anymore. The theme name has changed to silver and the skin names have changed as well.

Comment: Update Links to                     
SRC:                                  

         "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
         "node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js",
         "node_modules/tinymce/icons/default/icons.min.js"
                       
and                                
CSS                                                                           

        "node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css",
        "node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css",
        "node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.inline.min.css"

Comment: Why not just follow the section "TinyMCE Self-hosted" in official documentation: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#loadingtinymcebyyourself.

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer can be much more simplified following it [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#tinymceangularintegrationquickstartguide). Instead of adding the CSS files with their directories hard-coded, simply use this in `angular.json` instead:

```
 "assets": [
   { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce", "output": "/tinymce/" }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

That component simply needs TinyMCE available before you try to load TinyMCE via the component.  If TinyMCE is not there the component tries to load TinyMCE from the TinyMCE Cloud platform.  The fact that its trying to get it from the Cloud tells me TinyMCE was not already there.

You have options for loading TinyMCE.

**TinyMCE  tag in head of your document (Easy)**

If you have TinyMCE on your web server you can just use a script tag to load TinyMCE via your index.html page.  All aspects of your app would then have access to TinyMCE as its loaded when the app first loads

**Load TinyMCE via Module Loaders only when needed (Moderate Difficulty)**

You can use a module loader to load TinyMCE in the component(s) that need TinyMCE.  In theory you then only load TinyMCE when someone could need it but this approach is certainly more work to setup.

Documentation:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/

**Which of these should I use?**
Neither of these is the "right" or "wrong" approach - they are both viable and depending on your needs either can work just fine.