# Typeerror: Tinymce in undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

[image: I have included the plugin in the following way]Integrated Tinymce editor in Angular 8 and created an external plugin. Everything is working fine except it shows error on the console that tinymce is not defined in plugin.js file which is the code below.

```
    var tinymce;
    let dictionary = (function () {
        'use strict';

          tinymce.PluginManager.add("dictionary", function (editor, url) {

            editor.ui.registry.addAutocompleter('autocompleter-dictionary', {
                ch: '#', // the trigger character to open the autocompleter
                minChars: 2, // lower number means searching sooner - but more lookups as we go
                columns: 1, // must be 1 for text-based results
                fetch: function (pattern) {
                    return new tinymce.util.Promise(function (resolve) {
                        // call the countries REST endpoint to look up the query, and return the name and flag
                        fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + pattern + '?fields=name;dictionary')
                            .then((resp) => resp.json()) // convert response to json
                            .then(function (data) {
                                let results = [];
```

I have tried adding declare var tinymce: any; on typing.d.ts but doesnt work.

Comment: How did you install tinymce?

Comment: npm install --save @tinymce/tinymce-angular

Comment: Did you import it the way it should? Are you sure in your page tinymce exists? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302176/9942418

Comment: I am sure that I've followed all the steps specified there.

Comment: How is your plugin included? Are you sure it's included after the tinyce script?

Comment: @David I've added a picture to show how the plugin has been included.

Comment: I've tried and it seems to work for me, with or without the `var tinymce` actually. So there must be something else calling your plugin before tinymce is ready, or overwriting the `tinymce` variable